# file uploading not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I am trying to upload a file in nodejs using express and multer.

**index.js**

```
var mysql=require('mysql');
var session = require('express-session');
var multer=require('multer');
var express=require('express');
var path=require('path');
var cors=require('cors');
var nodemailer=require('nodemailer');
var fileupload=require('express-fileupload');
var fs=require('fs');
const app=express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(fileupload());
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '5mb',extended:true}));
require('./routes.js')(app,mc,fs,multer);
app.listen(8080,function() {
        console.log('port listening on 8080');
})
```

**routes.js**

```
module.exports=function(app,mc,fs,multer) {
    var storages = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        console.log(file)
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + 
    path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
    })

app.post('/reactTest',function(req,res) {

    var uploads = multer({
        storage: storages,
        fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
            var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
            if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
                res.send('Only images are allowed');
            }
            else {
                fs.exists('./uploads/'+file.originalname, function(exists) {    
                    console.log(exists);
                    if(exists) {
                        res.send('images already uploaded');
                    }
                    else {  
                        callback(null, true);
                    }
                })
            }   
        }
    }).single('user.uploadContent');
    uploads(req, res, function(err) {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.send('File is uploaded');
    })

})
    app.get('/',function(req,res) {
        var localTutor=require('./child.js');
        localTutor.NodeTutorial()();
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        res.write('<form action="fileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
        res.write('<input type="file" name="files" >');
        res.write('<br><input type="submit" >');
        res.write('</form>');
        res.send();
        //return res.send({error:true,message:'working'});
            //res.render('html');
    })
    app.post('/fileUpload',function(req,res) {

        var uploads = multer({
            storage: storages
        }).single('files');
        uploads(req, res, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }
            return res.send({status:'file uploaded'});
        })
    })

}
```

**front-end**

```
handleSubmit=(values,event)=> {
        console.log(values);
        const forms=new FormData(event.target);
        let promise=fetch('http://localhost:8080/reactTest', {
                method:'POST',
                mode:'CORS',
                body:forms,
                headers:{

                }

        }).then(res =>res.json()).then(result=>console.log(result)) 

    }
```

when i  uploaded a file it returns status as "file uploaded", but the file is doesn't uploaded to the directory.I don't know what the issue here is?
I am also attaching the code to create a restful api at front-end side.

Comment: do you check your upload folder have correct permission?

Comment: ya its having all permission.

Comment: maybe `fileupload` module conflict with `multer`?

Comment: 'path' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @wdetac  said , remove `app.use(fileupload());` then add  `var path=require('path');` to your `routes.js` file

a working example

**views/index.ejs**

```
<form action="fileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
id="form-id">
    <input type="file" id="file-select" name="files" multiple/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
    <button type="submit" id="upload-button">Upload</button>
</form>

<script>

var form = document.getElementById('form-id');
var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select');
var uploadButton = document.getElementById('upload-button');

form.onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();


  var files = fileSelect.files;
  var formData = new FormData();
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];

      if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      formData.append('files', file, file.name);
    }
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    formData.append('email',email);
    let promise=fetch('http://localhost:8080/reactTest', {
                method:'POST',
                mode:'CORS',
                body:formData

        }).then(res =>res.json()).then(result=>console.log(result)) 
}

</script>
```

**routes.js**

```
    app.post('/reactTest',function(req,res) {

    var uploads = multer({
        storage: storages,
        fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
            var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
            if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
                res.send('Only images are allowed');
            }
            else {
                fs.exists('uploads/'+file.originalname, function(exists) {    
                    console.log(exists);
                    if(exists) {
                        res.send('images already uploaded');
                    }
                    else {  
                        callback(null, true);
                    }
                })
            }   
        }
    }).single('files');
    uploads(req, res, function(err) {
        console.log('----------',req.body);
        res.send('File is uploaded');
    })

})
```

Comment: how can i retrieve form data object when i remove the app.use(fileupload()) ?

Comment: you can access to it by 'req.file'  'uploads(req, res, function(err) {
   console.log(req.file);'

Comment: ok.But I am also appending some other contents to the form data object.How can i retreiev that without using express-fileupload.                    eg:(formdata.append("fname":"pinto"))                                                         how can i retrieve the fname from the form data object without using express-fileupload?

Comment: if you are takking about inputs data check req.body

Comment: at front-end side i am sending form data content without adding any headers and trying to retrieve the response by convert it into res.json().But it is failed .what the issue here is?

Comment: i am edited the question with my front-end side code.please check it.

Comment: in you routes.js you are not handling reactTest route with post method

Comment: sorry i am forgot to add the code because of reducing the size.I am added it to the routes.js.